# Algebraic manipulation including Dirichlet-kernel and $2\pi$-periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, proof-explanation, periodic-functions

I came across an algebraic manipulation which I don't understand. Maybe someone can explain it to me.

For a fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we are given the integral:
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x+u)D_n(u)du,$$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function which is *Riemann*-integrable over $[-\pi,\pi]$. $D_n(u)$ is the $n$-th *Dirichlet*-kernel.

Our professor did the following manipulations where he substituted $u=-v$:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x+u)D_n(u)du\underset{\text{substitution}}{=}\frac{-1}{\pi} \int\limits_{\pi}^{-\pi}f(x-v)D_n(-v)dv =\frac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-v)D_n(v)dv.$$

Where does the $-1$ in the fraction after the first equal sign come from?

---

When I did the manipulation I got:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x+u)D_n(u)du\underset{\text{substitution}}{=}\frac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{\pi}^{-\pi}f(x-v)D_n(-v)dv =\frac{-1}{\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-v)D_n(v)dv.$$

Comment: $dv=-du$ so the sign changes

Comment: Ouh my bad, thank you :)

Comment: no problem - happy to be of help